# Does a SELECT query always return rows in the same order? Table with clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Will my `select *` query always return the rows from my database table in the same order?

My table has a 'clustered index' on one column. Does that change the answer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The order of the returned rows will **not** always be the same unless you explicitly state so with the `ORDER BY` clause. So, no.

And no; just because your 1000 queries have returned the same order it's **no** guarantee the 1001th query will be in the same order.

Comment: Maybe add some emphasis on the words **not** and **no**, since I misread your answer the first time.

Comment: Just to add to the picture: the Clustered Index determines how data is stored on disk, so it will be sorted on disk. HOWEVER, there are extreme fringe cases where things like parallelization can throw off the sorting when selecting.

Comment: Thanks bos. I was concerned 'order by' would be slow. I since compared 'execution plans' in SQL Studio—there is zero cost to ordering by the 'clustered index' column. Henceforth I shall be shockingly explicit.

Comment: @MikeM. - even then, it gets freaky - the clustered index determines the page order, but within a page, rows can appear "unordered" with respect to the index order (only their ordinals are guaranteed)

Comment: @ColonelPanic: If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to "accept" it.

Comment: @bos what is your source for this information - can you please list it?