# Will EntityFramework where clause always return objects in same order

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

For example, will

```
products.Where(p => p.LastModifiedOn > someDate)
```

always return the products with the same order (Doesn't matter how it's ordered, as long as it's consistent every time I call the same code)? Or should I add `.OrderBy()` method to make sure?

Comment: What is schema of your table? what is database you use ?

Comment: Can you also elaborate a little more why you dont care about order of elements and only if it is the same? What if you have some records as result of the query, and will have another set of records next time? I belive your LastModifiedOn field is timestamp so it is likely to happen.

Comment: @vittore I think you misunderstood my question. I do care about the order of elements and that's what I was asking. Habib's answer below is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, what exactly you mean by this `Doesn't matter how it's ordered, as long as it's consistent every time I call the same code)` then?

Comment: And consider you will have [(a, today) , (b, yesterday)] records when you run your query first time and [(b, today), (c, today)] next time. is it the same order or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or should I add .OrderBy() method to make sure?

Yes **you should**. It internally tranlsates into underlaying datasource language for example  `Select * from table where ...` and its returned values are not guaranteed to be in same order always.

You may see this question: [Does a SELECT query always return rows in the same order? Table with clustered index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584813/does-a-select-query-always-return-rows-in-the-same-order-table-with-clustered-i)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL does not preserve order.  Since you mentioned EntityFramework, that's the answer to your question.  You should note, however, that LINQ to Objects does preserve order - the same order as the input enumerable.

Comment: EntityFramework does not use Linq-to-SQL. It uses Linq-to-Entities.