# Do clustered index on a column GUARANTEES returning sorted rows according to that column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to get clear cut answers on this contentious question .
[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx) mentions

Clustered

- Clustered indexes **sort** and store the data rows in the table or view
  based on their key values. These are the columns included in the
  index definition. There can be only one clustered index per table,
  because the data rows themselves can be **sorted** in only one order.
- The only time the data rows in a table are stored in **sorted** order is
  when the table contains a clustered index. When a table has a
  clustered index, the table is called a clustered table. If a table
  has no clustered index, its data rows are stored in an unordered
  structure called a heap.

While I see most of the answers

- [Does a SELECT query always return rows in the same order? Table with clustered index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584813/does-a-select-query-always-return-rows-in-the-same-order-table-with-clustered-i)
- http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2013/06/02/clustered-index-do-not-guarantee-physically-ordering-or-sorting-of-rows/

answering negative.

What is it ?

Comment: Returning sorted rows in general has nothing to do with storing sorted rows. The server might return output sorted on the clustered index if it thinks that will be cheaper, but there is no guarantee unless `order by` is used.

Comment: Seems to be an exact duplicate. What is not answered for you? The answer is a very clear no.

Comment: The answer is a clear: NO. The only (really: the only) way to **guarantee** an order is to use `order by`.

Comment: voting to reopen, as this question has more and better answers.  The other question should be closed as the duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to be clear.  Presumably, you are talking about a simple query such as:

```
select *
from table t;
```

First, if all the data on the table fits on a single page and there are no other indexes on the table, it is hard for me to imagine a scenario where the result set is not ordered by the primary key.  However, this is because I think the most reasonable query plan would require a full-table scan, not because of any requirement -- documented or otherwise -- in SQL or SQL Server.  Without an explicit `order by`, the ordering in the result set is a consequence of the query plan.

That gets to the heart of the issue.  When you are talking about the ordering of the result sets, you are really talking about the query plan.  And, the assumption of ordering by the primary key really means that you are assuming that the query uses full-table scan.  What is ironic is that people make the assumption, without actually understanding the "why".  Furthermore, people have a tendency to generalize from small examples (okay, this is part of the basis of human intelligence).  Unfortunately, they see consistently that results sets from simple queries on small tables are always in primary key order and generalize to larger tables.  The induction step is incorrect in this example.

What can change this?  Off-hand, I think that a full table scan would return the data in primary key order if the following conditions are met:

- Single threaded server.
- Single file filegroup
- No competing indexes
- No table partitions

I'm not saying this is always true.  It just seems reasonable that under these circumstances such a query would use a full table scan starting at the beginning of the table.

Even on a small table, you can get surprises.  Consider:

```
select NonPrimaryKeyColumn
from table
```

The query plan would probably decide to use an index on `table(NonPrimaryKeyColumn)` rather than doing a full table scan.  The results would not be ordered by the primary key (unless by accident).  I show this example because indexes can be used for a variety of purposes, not just `order by` or `where` filtering.

If you use a multi-threaded instance of the database and you have reasonably sized tables, you will quickly learn that results without an `order by` have no explicit ordering.

And finally, SQL Server has a pretty smart optimizer.  I think there is some reluctance to use `order by` in a query because users think it will automatically do a sort.  SQL Server works hard to find the best execution plan for the query.  IF it recognizes that the `order by` is redundant because of the rest of the plan, then the `order by` will not result in a sort.

And, of course you want to guarantee the ordering of results, you need `order by` in the outermost query.  Even a query like this:

```
select *
from (select top 100 t.* from t order by col1) t
```

Does not guarantee that the results are ordered in the final result set.  You really need to do:

```
select *
from (select top 100 t.* from t order by col1) t
order by col1;
```

to guarantee the results in a particular order.  This behavior *is* documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

Comment: So what I have understood is that clustered index stores data in sorted manner in the sense that it is stored in a B+ Tree where nodes are decided according to the column value on which index has been created.

Comment: this storage in sorted manner DOES NOT guarantee that running a `Select * from table` query will give sorted resultset according to Column values on which clustered index was created .

Comment: Databases have more than one way to read data in a table.  Even if the table is stored in sorted order, the table can be read via an index or using multiple threads that invalidate that order.

Comment: For you single/multi-threaded point - are you talking about parallelism within a single plan or the ability for the system to use another query's already running table scan to obtain part of its results?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . I'm referring multiple threads within a single plan that read a table.  The processing won't be in sequential order, because different sets of data will go to different threads.

Answer (score 7):

**Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order even if you have clustered index**

in [**this link**](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) there is a good example :

```
CREATE SCHEMA Data AUTHORIZATION dbo 
GO 
CREATE TABLE Data.Numbers(Number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) 
GO 
DECLARE @ID INT; 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET @ID = 1; 
WHILE @ID < 100000 BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO Data.Numbers(Number) 
 SELECT @ID; 
 SET @ID = @ID+1; 
END 

CREATE TABLE Data.WideTable(ID INT NOT NULL  
CONSTRAINT PK_WideTable PRIMARY KEY, 
RandomInt INT NOT NULL, 
CHARFiller CHAR(1000)) 
GO 
CREATE VIEW dbo.WrappedRand 
AS 
SELECT RAND() AS random_value 
GO 
CREATE ALTER FUNCTION dbo.RandomInt() 
RETURNS INT 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @ret INT; 
SET @ret = (SELECT random_value*1000000 FROM dbo.WrappedRand); 
RETURN @ret; 
END 
GO 

INSERT INTO Data.WideTable(ID,RandomInt,CHARFiller) 
SELECT Number, dbo.RandomInt(), 'asdf' 
FROM Data.Numbers 
GO 
CREATE INDEX WideTable_RandomInt ON Data.WideTable(RandomInt) 
GO 
SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM Data.WideTable
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1407
253
9175
6568
4506
1623
581
```

> As you have seen, the optimizer has chosen to use a non-clustered
>   index to satisfy this SELECT TOP query.
>
> Clearly you cannot assume that your results are ordered unless you
>   explicitly use ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

One must specify `ORDER BY` in the outermost query in order to guarantee rows are returned in a particular order.  The SQL Server optimizer will optimize the query and data access to improve performance which may result in rows being returned in a different order.  Examples of this are allocation order scans and parallelism.  A relational table should always be viewed as an unordered set of rows.

I wish the MSDN documentation were clearer about this "sorting".  It is more correct to say that SQL Server b-tree indexes provide ordering by 1) storing adjacent keys in the same page and 2) linking index pages in key order.