# How to sort table result within a function SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create function that's return a sorted table based in a column value,
I know that's order by doesn't work in function or view a searched her and in others website but I didn't find any things, so my idea is to use a basic ALGORITHME like in C or C++

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

You cant make a function return the data in any order.

You just order the result

```
  SELECT  *
  FROM dbo.someFunction () 
  ORDER BY somefield
```

Read:

[Do clustered index on a column GUARANTEES returning sorted rows according to that column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126252/do-clustered-index-on-a-column-guarantees-returning-sorted-rows-according-to-tha)
[How does sql server sort your data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040724/how-does-sql-server-sort-your-data)