# How to assign duplicate increment in SQL?

Tags: sql

While going through SQL columns, if we find text match "NEW" in `Calc` column, update the incrementing a count starting with 1 in `Results` column.

It should look like this on the output:

[image]

Comment: SQL Data Sets have no order, in-fact they are explicitly un-ordered.  To accomplish what you want you need to use one or more additional columns to calulate the ordering from.  Do you have such a column?  If so, please add it to your example.  Also, which database are you using?  Different databases have different syntax... *(MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc, etc?)*

Comment: @dhans in order to get better answers you should included the DDL of the table plus a few insert statements to add the data you're showing here. This will allow for quicker replication of your data and quicker answers.

Comment: @MatBailie Not sure how you can say that the table is explicitly un-ordered without knowing any of the answers to the questions you're asking following that very declarative answer. I think your comment is strongly dependent on the answer to the questions following it.

Comment: @peter4499 - Because it's an explicit property of ALL sql tables that they are unordered sets.  It's not that THIS table is unordered, it's that in sql ALL tables are unordered sets. The order of rows, and thus their position relative to each other ONLY exists as a function of the data, as expressable by an ORDER BY clause. As that ORDER BY clause can only be specified in a query, and can be different in each query, the *table itself* does not posses an inherent ordering. In this case the OP did not include any such data until After I left my comment, as can be seen by the OP's edit history.

Comment: @MatBailie You're missing my point. Tables can have ordered, that's literally what a clustered index does... You're 100% correct that you should not rely on this. The OP even after updating his questions never specified this, but your swiping declaration about SQL tables is misleading. At the very least, not pertinent to this question. In order to not digress I'll won't be joining the discussion on this. I don't want it to turn into a weird flame war on who can school who :) Thanks for you contributions!!!

Comment: @peter4499 I'm not missing your point. Even a clustered index does NOT imbue a table with and inherent order. Even with a clustered index a multitude of factors can cause rows to be processed in different orders. There is NO concept of a row being before or after another row without an ORDER BY clause. I'm not espousing my opinion, I'm communicating part of the definition of sql itself. If you disagree, I suggest you refer to questions such as this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126252/do-clustered-index-on-a-column-guarantees-returning-sorted-rows-according-to-tha/28126361

Comment: @peter4499 From `ISO/IEC 9075-1:1999 (E) ©ISO/IEC`
3.1 Deﬁnitions, section x. `x) table: A table has an ordered collection of one or more columns and an unordered collection of zero or more rows. Each column has a name and a data type. Each row has, for each column, exactly one value in the data type of that column.`  Let me highlight that... ***unordered collection of zero or more rows***. BY DEFINITION.

Comment: It looks like the question has been changed to include a `rank` column.  That will change the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses an id column to resolve the order issue.  Replace that with your corresponding expression.  This also addresses the requirement to start the display sequence with 1 and also show 0 for the 'NEW' rows.

The SQL (*updated*):

```
SELECT logs.*
     , CASE WHEN text = 'NEW' THEN 0
            ELSE 
                COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN text = 'NEW' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY xrank ORDER BY id)+1, 1)
            END AS display
  FROM logs
 ORDER BY id
```

The result:

```
+----+-------+------+---------+
| id | xrank | text | display |
+----+-------+------+---------+
|  1 |     1 | A    |       1 |
|  2 |     1 | B    |       1 |
|  3 |     1 | C    |       1 |
|  4 |     1 | NEW  |       0 |
|  5 |     1 | D    |       2 |
|  6 |     1 | Q    |       2 |
|  7 |     1 | B    |       2 |
|  8 |     1 | NEW  |       0 |
|  9 |     1 | D    |       3 |
| 10 |     1 | Z    |       3 |
| 11 |     2 | A    |       1 |
| 12 |     2 | B    |       1 |
| 13 |     2 | C    |       1 |
| 14 |     2 | NEW  |       0 |
| 15 |     2 | D    |       2 |
| 16 |     2 | Q    |       2 |
| 17 |     2 | B    |       2 |
| 18 |     2 | NEW  |       0 |
| 19 |     2 | D    |       3 |
| 20 |     2 | Z    |       3 |
+----+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your query, your query working when only one set of Rank. Suppose if have more than 3 set  it will not work

Comment: @dhans I don't know what you mean by `one set of rank`.  The example has at least 3 groups.  Can you add an example to your question with `two or more sets of rank` and describe what you mean by `rank`.  I know what `rank` means in SQL, but not as you are using it.  Did you change the question?

Comment: @dhans Answer has been updated with an example having 2 sets of xrank.

Answer (score 0):

You need a column that specifies the ordering for the table.  With that, just use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       1 + sum(case when Calc = 'NEW' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Rank_Id order by Seq) as display
from t;
```

Comment: To be complete, this should show `0` when the `text` value is `'NEW'`, and then have a `+ 1` to start the cumulative sum from `1`.

Comment: Your answer use full , little correction on your query "Display" need to start with 1 So,  select t.*,
       (sum(case when text = 'NEW' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by [seq])) + 1as display
from t;