# Exporting table in a specific SQL database to a new database

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table in SQL that's in a database. I've performed sort operations as well as catching a certain amount of records, and now my objective is to input these values into a new database. How can I do this, considering the sort operations? Would it be potentially easier to export the whole table then perform the sort in the new database? I am using SQL 2005.

Comment: Tables don't have a "sort" or an "order". They are a collection of data. If you want the data returned in a certain order then you need to express that in your query. It doesn't make any sense to say that you're sorting data to put into a table.

Comment: Actually @tom-h, Tables can be sorted based on their Clustered Index, either ASC (ending, default) or DESC (ending).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190457.aspx

Comment: No, that merely determines the underlying storage of the data. A table itself has no notion of a "sort". If you `SELECT` from a table with a clustered index you are not guaranteed to get your data back in that order. It may be a subtle difference, but it's a very important one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: As Tom H is saying using a clustered index will not guarantee a perfectly sorted table.  [This has already been discussed multiple times on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584813/does-a-select-query-always-return-rows-in-the-same-order-table-with-clustered-i).  Using a sort or order would be the only guaranteed way of getting sorted data.

Comment: All of that said - having the data presorted could have performance impacts on the transfer of the data as it's added into the new table. Your question doesn't include nearly enough information to determine whether or not this is going to be a concern though.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what order you insert the data into the new table.   If you put a clustered index on the table, the data will be stored in the order of the index, regardless of the order it was inserted.   (And note that storing it in this order is no guarantee that your query results will come out in this order)

The only instance where the order of inserts might matter is if you have an IDENTITY column on the table, and are allowing it to auto-populate.   Then the IDENTITY will increment in the order that the rows are inserted.

That said, treating your question as academic, if you did want to export data in a certain order from one database to another, you could use an SSIS dataflow and specify an ORDER BY in the query in the Source component.